How to fix `cargo clippy` error for `#[pallet::call]` and `#[pallet::generate_deposit(pub(crate) fn deposit_event)]`
I have added a clippy check #![warn(clippy::missing_docs_in_private_items)] on the top of my pallet. I have added documents at all required places. However I am still getting below errors for #[pallet::call] and #[pallet::generate_deposit(pub(crate) fn deposit_event)].
error: missing documentation for a module
   --> pallets/abc/src/lib.rs:810:12
    |
810 |     #[pallet::call]
    |               ^^^^
    |
    = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#missing_docs_in_private_items
    = note: `-D clippy::missing-docs-in-private-items` implied by `-D warnings`
    = help: to override `-D warnings` add `#[allow(clippy::missing_docs_in_private_items)]`

error: missing documentation for an associated function
   --> pallets/abc/src/lib.rs:115:29
    |
115 |     #[pallet::generate_deposit(pub(crate) fn deposit_event)]
    |                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |
    = help: for further information visit https://rust-lang.github.io/rust-clippy/master/index.html#missing_docs_in_private_items



Can somebody please suggest how to fix these errors?

You can't fix these clippy errors locally. If you want to keep #![warn(clippy::missing_docs_in_private_items)].
Those code is generated by a macro defined in upstream.
You'll need to submit a PR to the polkadot-sdk to address this. However, I doubt this because private items don't always need documentation, and this clippy flag is set to false by default.
